# Both REST API of Tradingview and Interactive Brokers connect by python successful?

Tags: api, interactive-brokers, tradingview-api

Is anyone successful connect the two REST API of Tradingview and Interactive Brokers by python?Can give me some guidance or sample?thanks.

Comment: https://www.interactivebrokers.com/api/doc.html

Comment: https://in.tradingview.com/rest-api-spec/

Comment: both api are RESTful.